# Url rewriting: url pointing to a different server than the one specified in the RECORD A DNS

Tags: apache

I have the domain "www.first.com" which points x.x.x.x
I have the domain "www.second.com" which points to y.y.y.y
I want the to type in the browser "www.first.com" and get to "www.second.com" (on the y.y.y.y) but the url showed in the browser has to be the same!

If I put a .htaccess inside the x.x.x.x server with: 
       `RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule index.php http://www.second.com`

I get to second.com, but the url is changed to http://www.second.com. Is there anyway to achieve what I want to do?

1 - It's because I need to host a website on my server, but the domain doesn't point towards it and I MUST NOT CHANGE the dns.
2 - I can change some of the contents in the x.x.x.x server, but I can't neither change DNS or put the website directory inside it.

I was considering put a simple index.php in the x.x.x.x server, which make a eval(file_get_contents("www.second.com")): I know it's weird, but I can't get closer than that to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Apache mod_proxy might be the best way to achieve that.

Comment: ProxyRequests On 

<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass http://www.second.com
</Proxy> What's wrong with this?

Comment: I think those are for a forward proxy and what you need is a reverse proxy. The directives you need should be `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`. Make sure to remove that config as it might make your server an open proxy.

Comment: But I need all the web to visit www.first.com and get to www.second.com, then I have to let it open, right?

Comment: "It is not necessary to turn ProxyRequests on in order to configure a reverse proxy." - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html